# unable to install R package "nloptr" (R3.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04) - C++ compiler issue

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, package

I'm having trouble installing the "car" package after upgrading R to 3.6.2 (from 3.4) on Ubuntu 16.04 due to (at least one) dependency (nloptr) that cannot be installed either. It seems to be a problem of the C++ compiler (it is using some deprecated "config" settings, however I'm lost trying to fix this).

I called the following command in R (from the terminal):

> > install.packages("nloptr")

**Error Information:**

```
Installing package into ‘/home/heike/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://ftp.fau.de/cran/src/contrib/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2448313 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB
* installing source package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
'config' variable 'CPP' is deprecated
'config' variable 'CXXCPP' is deprecated
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in /tmp/RtmpPLaJFA/R.INSTALL5e5ed06eeac/nloptr': configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables See config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’
```

**Steps taken so far**

- changed CRAN mirror and source.list entry
- uninstalled and reinstalled R 3.6.2 (also on different machine), same issue remained

**System Information**

- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit))
- R Version: 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)

Comment: What is the content of `config.log`?

Comment: I don't know where to find config.log - it doesn't give me a directory.
>> find -iname config.log finds many log files that are non-R related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done a lot of work to make nloptr installation better.  In essence, you have several choices:

- if the *system version* of the nlopt library is present, use it -- that is the easiest so try installing it via `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev` and then reinstall
- if it is not found, then a download of the source and build happens, and this seems to fail on your almost four year old Ubuntu system as it is hard to support all flavours --- but this works swimmingly on newer ones (I run Ubuntu too, but currently 19.10)
- there are binaries for you as, see the [Ubuntu packages page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-nloptr) -- however these may not match your current R version which is mismatches to your distro R version
- dependening on where you got R from (did you install a .deb?) you could use the Michael Rutter PPAs to get a *current* r-cran-nloptr

All this can also be discussed in detail on the r-sig-debian list for R on Debian and Ubuntu.

*Edit:*  In response to the comment below:

- To see what package `apt` knows about, do `apt-cache policy r-cran-nloptr`. Per the link I gave above we *know* Ubuntu has a `r-cran-nloptr` for your (very old) Xenial installation. However it will clash with the very new and current R you have running.  Such as the costs of mixing and matching.
- To access the Rutter PPAs and its over four thousand *current* binaries see the fourth paragraph at the top of the [Ubuntu at CRAN README](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)

*Edit 2:*  I may have been too pessimistic. The Rutter PPA for the current R binaries has trusty, xenial and bionic. See https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5

Comment: Thank you. I installed the system version, but the issue remains. 

I installed R as:

`sudo apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys E084DAB9

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`

I'm not sure about your last two comments. Can you please give me a more specific hint on how to solve my issue using binaries/ M.R.'s PPA?

Comment: I understand from your answer that the cleanest way is to upgrade Ubuntu (I was planning to do that when 20.04 LTS is released because all other programs (mostly conda/python) are running just fine, and you know what upgrading Ubuntu can be like :) ). Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: Yes, I try to be polite but it is difficult (for us volunteers) to support to many flavours. Michael does a _fantastic_ service providing over 4k binaries and I (personally speaking) think the most current LTS is best. But I just checked and he seems to support trusty, xenial and bionic. So you may get `r-cran-nloptr` there too.  I still recommend upgrading to 18.04 though if you can, and then maybe later in the year to 20.04 :-)

Comment: Ok, cool! I'll try installing from Rutter's PPA tomorrow and will let you know if it fixed the issue (if it doesn't, I promise I'll upgrade!)